Unknown query node type: 'Constant'
We could see the lot of below exceptions in the Sitecore log file. Could you please provide some suggestions to resolve this issue?
Exception: System.NotSupportedException
Message: Unknown query node type: 'Constant'
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.Visit(QueryNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.Visit(QueryNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.MapQuery(IndexQuery query)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Linq.Parsing.DefaultQueryTranslator`1.GetQuery(Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Linq.Parsing.DefaultQueryExecutor`1.Execute[TElement,TResult](Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions.GetResults[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)


can you please share the Solr query which you are calling ..

Solr Query - ?q=((_group:("cff35512246d49ae9cf41fa78190a398") AND _latestversion:("True")) AND _language:("en")) AND val:__boost&start=0&rows=1000000&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:("indexname")&wt=xml

This is the correct solr query. There must be issue in dotnet code while creating query to Solr. Can you share that solr predicate builder code. There must be an error on the predicate builder.

We are getting the same error like in this article https://community.sitecore.com/community/en?id=community_question&sys_id=1815e3e51b4770d0b8954371b24bcbe4.
But we never used the || condition and only used the aggregate with or condition.
Are there any troubleshooting steps available?
